# eventtocommand ManipulationCompleted

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, mvvm-light

I'm having a go at writing a small media player for my Windows Phone (more for learning purposes if anything), and am using mvvm-light.
When a video is playing, I have a timer that periodically updates the slider position (and ensures that it's in sync). When I slide the slider around, I pause the timer, so it doesn't skip about.
I use the ManipulationStarted event to pause the timer, and ManipulationComplete to resume it.

I've tried using EventToCommand, but only the ManipulationStarted event fires. When I lift my finger off the phone, ManipulationComplete doesn't fire.

This is my xaml :

```
<Slider x:Name="PlaybackSlider" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="20,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Maximum="{Binding MaxSteps}" Value="{Binding Offset, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource SliderStyle1}" >
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="ManipulationStarted">
            <Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding PlayOffsetBegin}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="ManipulationCompleted">
            <Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding PlayOffsetEnd}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseMove">
            <Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding PlayOffsetUpdate}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Slider>
```

The bindings are relay commands.

If I implement it like this, it all works fine :

```
<Slider x:Name="PlaybackSlider" 
    ManipulationStarted="PlaybackSlider_ManipulationStarted" 
    ManipulationCompleted="PlaybackSlider_ManipulationCompleted" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="20,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
    Maximum="{Binding MaxSteps}" Value="{Binding Offset, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: check output window, maybe there is binding error. Codes you posted looks fine. Try to look into the rest of your code more closely, especially those related to `PlayOffsetEnd` Command.

Comment: Thanks, but no dice.
I even tried replacing the PlayOffsetEnd command with PlayOffsetBegin (which is known to work) with noeffect...